# Where on child's parent object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get all object where the childs parentId equals the page id.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
public IEnumerable<Route> GetAll(int locationId)
{
    _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return _db.Routes.Include(o => o.ConnectionPointRoutes.Select(s => s.Segment))
            .Include(o => o.ConnectionPointRoutes.Select(c => c.ConnectionPoint)
            .Where( c => c.Location.LocationId == locationId)).ToList();
}
```

but I keep getting this error :

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a
>   navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for
>   reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like c.Location is a list object so you need c.Location.Select( x => ......).  Do you have a multi-generation Table like Great-Grand-Parent ID, Grand Parent ID, Parent ID, Child ID?  If so you may need to use a recursive algorithm to get all the levels. Linq will only work on single generation list.

Comment: I don't think `Where` is supported inside the `Include`.

Comment: I found a way of fixing it, check the answer if you are interested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this :

```
    public IEnumerable<Route> GetAll(int locationId)
    {
        return _db.Routes
            .Include(o => o.ConnectionPointRoutes.Select(s => s.Segment))
            .Include(o => o.ConnectionPointRoutes.Select(c => c.ConnectionPoint))
            .Where(c => c.ConnectionPointRoutes.Select(s => s.ConnectionPoint.Location)
            .FirstOrDefault(q => q.LocationId == locationId).LocationId == locationId)
            .ToList();
    }
```